# How to count values greater than the group mean in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The dataframe is generated as follows. What's the best way to count how many values are greater than the average of grouped by ["A", "B"]?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
keys = np.array([['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'], ['A', 'B'],
                 ['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D'], ['C', 'D'],
                 ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['E', 'F'],
                 ['G', 'H']]) 
df = (pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([keys,np.random.randn(10,4).round(2)]),
                  columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3',
                             'col4', 'col5', 'col6'])
      .astype({'col3': float,
               'col4': float,
               'col5': float, 
               'col6': float}))
```

I tried to first count the mean and then join the grouped-dataframe back to the original one, then do a sum(1). But that appears to be a little tedious.

```
df2 = pd.merge(df.groupby(["col1", "col2"]).mean(), df, left_on=["col1", "col2"], right_on=["col1", "col2"])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need the `agg` method

```
In [28]: df.groupby(['col1', 'col2']).agg(lambda x: (x > x.mean()).sum())
Out[28]:
           col3  col4  col5  col6
col1 col2
A    B      1.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
C    D      2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
E    F      1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
G    H      0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

In essence, the `x` is going to be array-like.  `x > x.mean()` gives True if the element is larger than the mean and 0 otherwise, `sum` then counts the number of Trues.

Comment: This makes sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
(df[['col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6']]>df.groupby(['col1','col2']).transform('mean')).sum()

col3    4
col4    6
col5    3
col6    6
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `numpy.add.at` and `pandas.factorize`

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2']
i, r = pd.factorize([*zip(*map(df.get, cols))])

v = df.drop(cols, 1).values
n, m = shape = len(r), v.shape[1]

b = np.zeros(shape)
c = np.zeros(shape)
d = np.zeros(shape, np.int64)

i0, i1 = i.repeat(m), np.tile(np.arange(m), len(v))

np.add.at(b, (i0, i1), v.ravel())
np.add.at(c, (i0, i1), 1)
np.add.at(d, (i0, i1), (v > (b / c)[i]).ravel())

pd.DataFrame(
    d, pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(r, names=cols),
    df.columns.difference(cols)
)

           col3  col4  col5  col6
col1 col2                        
A    B        2     2     3     2
C    D        2     1     1     2
E    F        1     1     1     1
G    H        0     0     0     0
```